# Having trouble in formulating rules in excel

Tags: excel-formula

Example:

```
1 3 2 4 5 6 7
```

Rules:

1. If it is the first time a number is greater than its previous number, retrieve the number (3 in this instance);
2. If after the retrieved number, the subsequent number is less than or equal to "the retrieved number - 1", discard the retrieved number (3 will be discarded)(back to Rule (I), number 4 will be chosen);and
3. If the subsequent number is greater than the number retrieved, store the difference between subsequent numbers and number retrieved, show the largest difference between subsequent numbers and number retrieved(in this case 7-4)

I tried to formulate the rules in excel but I am stuck at Rule (II).

Let me know if I am unclear, I'll try to be as explicit as possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure I got the rules exactly right, but maybe this will help.

I put the numbers in a column and made two helper columns. See the image.

[image]

In `B3`, enter
`=IF(LEN(B2)=0,IF(A3>A2,A3,""),IF(A3<=B2-1,IF(A3>A2,A3,""),B2))`
and fill down.

In `C3`, enter
`=IF(LEN(B3)=0,"",IF(B3<A3,A3-B3,""))`
and fill down.

The largest difference will be `=MAX(C:C)`.